# Access to public IP - Amazon instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm running some node services on an Amazon instance (EC2), the service were deployed using ssh over the instance, but for some reason, I can't access to the service using the public IP, but all the services are running. Is necessary enable the public IP in the configuration of my EC2 setting or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your security group has the proper ports opened up. In the EC2 console, go to Security Groups (on the left side of the page). Find the security group of the EC2 instance.
There is a tab called Inbound. Make sure you have a row with the type = SSH, protocol = TCP, port = 22, and source = 0.0.0.0/0

[image]
[image]